# Script to kill a specified process when it reached some % cpu

Tags: scripts

I have an Ubuntu server 20. I am running 4 processes with the following names:

```
project-A
project-B
project-C
project-D
```

All is running good but some times I see one of the projects consuming CPU and reaches to 300%.

So I want script to kill (for example) "project-B" when it reaches 300% CPU.

Comment: Would limiting resources from the beginning be an adequate alternative?

Comment: I like the suggestion from @Fiximan. Also, I'd suggest a threshold and a time period, e.g. "above 250% for 5 seconds".

Comment: thanks @bitinerant but when i use cpu limit these process hangs and stuck i just want to kill it and with another script i have it run again  so i still need the script that kills it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should kill any `md5sum` process which uses more than 50% CPU. Replace the `md5sum` and `50` as needed.

```
while true; do
    PID=$(pidof -s md5sum || cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max)
    if [[ $(ps -p $PID -o %cpu= |grep -Po '^\s*\K[0-9]+') -gt 50 ]]; then
        echo killing PID $PID
        kill $PID
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

**Notes:**

- Try `pidof -s your_process` to make sure it works before replacing `md5sum` in the above script.
- If the above does not actually kill the process, it may be necessary to use the brute force `kill -9 $PID` instead of `kill $PID`, but only do this if the first method doesn't work.
- To do the above once (without a loop) in a single line:

```
PID=$(pidof -s md5sum || cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max); if [[ $(ps -p $PID -o %cpu= |grep -Po '^\s*\K[0-9]+') -gt 50 ]]; then echo killing PID $PID; kill $PID; fi
```

**Explanations:**

- `while true; do ... sleep 1; done` loop until ctrl-c is pressed; this also allows killing of multiple matching processes
- `pidof -s md5sum || cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` first (`-s`) process id of an md5sum process, or a non-existent PID if there aren't any
- `ps -p $PID -o %cpu=` CPU utilization of the $PID process as a decimal percentage
- `|grep -Po '^\s*\K[0-9]+'` strip CPU percentage to an integer
- `if [[ ... -gt 50 ]]` if ... is greater than 50

Comment: hi thank you for your replay

can i delete the while true and use killall -9 so the script look like that 

MAX_PID=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max)
    PID=$(pidof -s md5sum || echo $MAX_PID)
    if [[ $(ps -p $PID -o %cpu= |grep -Po '^\s*\K[0-9]+') -gt 50 ]]; then
        echo killing PID $PID
        killall -9 $PID
    fi
exit 0

Comment: @nano66nano66 - that's close. Your version needs semicolons between statements, `kill` rather than `killall`, and no `exit 0`. I added it under "Notes", above. Be sure to replace `kill $PID` with `kill -9 $PID`.

Comment: thank you very much it worked like charm

Comment: @nano66nano66 - you're very welcome. Can you mark it as the accepted answer, then (check mark on the left)?